# Error: RHS may contain only factor variables

Tags: r

I have a csv file containing data on levels of compression of soil and the penetrability of water based on Compact, Intermediate, or Loose (C, I and L)
the file contains list of compression values (C, I and L) under comp and arbitrary values for penetration under pent. I am just trying to create a simple histogram but no matter how much or little detail I put into the code I always get the error
Error: RHS may contain only factor variables.

```
library(FSA)
attach(SoilCompression)
hist(pent ~ comp, las=1,
 nrow=1, ncol=3,
 cex.main=0.9, cex.lab=0.8, cex.axis=0.8,
 ylab="Penetrability"
)
```

Comment: A side note: use of `attach` is generally discouraged. It can cause some weird problems.  You could wrap your `hist` function with `with` instead.

Comment: What does `class(SoilCompression$comp)` tell you?

Comment: class(SoilCompression$comp) returns
[1] "character"

Comment: `hist` takes a single variable, not a formula.  Perhaps you need a different type of plot?

Comment: @AndrewGustar Note the package they are loading.

Comment: @user2239009 Well, make that variable a factor variable. Use the `factor` function.

Comment: @Roland - yes, sorry about that!

Comment: @Roland Thanks so much, never really used this kind of interface before its just for Uni (I would kill to use a calculator,pen and paper right about now)